# appending one object to another in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created two objects as shown in the below script. I'm able to append them onto the page using 'document.body'. Now, I wanted to append 'appItem' into header which is in 'mainWrapper'. how can I do this.

```
function mainWrapper() {
    var wrapper;
    var header;

    function create() {
        wrapper = document.createElement('div');
        header = document.createElement('div');
        wrapper.appendChild(header);
    }

    function style() {
        wrapper.className = "wrapper";
        header.className = "header";
    }

    function init() {
        create();
        style();
    }
    init();
    this.render = function (k) {
        k.appendChild(wrapper);
    }
}

function appItem() {
    var appItemIcon;
    appItemIcon = document.createElement('img');
    appItemIcon.src = 'icons/list.png';
    this.appItemRender = function (k) {
        k.appendChild(appItemIcon);
    }
}
window.addEventListener('load', onLoad);

function onLoad() {
    var main = new mainWrapper();
    var appList = new appItem();
    main.render(document.body);
    appList.appItemRender(document.body);
}
```

Comment: I don't get why you need these little `render` function inside it, they're confusing. Just use `document.body.appendChild()` directly.

Comment: Try to make the `header` available on `mainWrapper` instances (as a property, or through a getter method) so that you can render your `appList` to it.